# API Request from another domain via AJAX

Tags: ajax, cross-platform

I have a project that will need to pull data from other site and they have an API. Id like to perform ajax calls to pull data from other site and populate my spans and divs.

So i heres my ajax flow:  ajax call -> retriever.php  -> API server.

I am aware of the cross domain policy and ive done much research for solutions but still its not clear to me.

My questions are:

Is jsonp requires server cooperation, i mean, Does the API server i am communicating to needs to support jsonp?

Second question is, what are other solutions for my project.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First,jsonp is supported by brower.
Second,you can use RPC for your project.

Comment: Thank you for the help guolei. I am new to jsonp, i will read much more on it and also your suggestion RPC. :)